# How can I handle Facebook likes, gifs and stickers inside of my Bot Framework chatbot?

Tags: botframework, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I have created a chatbot using the Microsoft Bot Framework. The only channel I'm interested in right now it's Facebook. When doing some tests on Facebook I've noticed that when I click on the "Like" button, and when I send an gif or audio message, the bot crashes with the following message:

> "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: stringToEscape."

How can I handle this kind of message within my bot? I can't replicate this on the emulator, so I don't know what Facebook is sending to my bot when the user sends one of these kind of messages. I would like to just ignore them and avoid the bot crashing.

Comment: Is that stringToEscape a variable in your code? Are u accessing to the ChannelData of the activity?

Comment: @EzequielJadib stringToEscape is not in my code. And I'm not accessing the ChannelData of the activity at any moment.

Comment: Have you tried to debug this? Run your bot locally, use ngrok and update the bot url in the dev portal to use the ngrok one. Also, try to post your code; otherwise it will be hard to know what's going on.

Comment: @EzequielJadib I'll look into using ngrok to debug, I have found a workaround for now, but I think it's a poor solution to the problem. I'm currently just ignoring Activities with an empty Text property. I'l post the code when I configure ngrok. Thank you.

Comment: If you post the details of the activity you are receiving, I can provide a better workaround. I might have a clue of how to solve it better.

Comment: Did anything more solid come out of this? Care to share the solution? The empty Text property would work but it's also a pretty blunt solution.